# URL rewriting in WordPress with one parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a page named "city":

```
http://localhost/wordpress/city/
```

It gets details from MySQL by URL id like:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/city/?id=paris
```

I want to change it like:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/city/paris
```

The real link of the city page in WordPress is:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/index.php?p=5
```

I try `add_rewrite_rule`, but it doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_mypage_rule' );
function add_mypage_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%id%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^city/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=5&id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

What `add RewriteRule` should I use for `.htaccess`?